# C# / WPF I don't know how and where to calculate Monthly payment for Mortgage calculator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have finished most of the code but now I don't know where and how to start calculation for Monthly Payment.
I have passed inputs to local variables.
I did try calculating at the bottom. so please assist me.

Comment: what is wrong with this code? are you getting any error or exception? could you please edit the question with relevant cods only

Comment: I'm not sure how do I go back and edit the post but when I put in all values and click submit button it doesn't show anything. I thing my calculation is wrong (the way it's written).

Comment: You don't have brackets around the three lines after the `else` statement so execution never reaches the calculation or the `MessageBox.Show(MonthPay)` line.  The IDE is likely giving you a warning about unreachable code.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are talking about the code after below that is missing brackets. if you are than I have put brackets around it and it still doesn't work.
    else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select number of years.");
                    stkrdobtns.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    return;
                }

Comment: This doesn't compile. `monthlypayement` is defined as `int` and the calculation produces a `double`. Even fixing that and with the last `else` clause properly bracketed the `mothlypayment` calculation is still unreachable. It looks like the `return`s in the first 3 `if` cases need to be commented out. Once you do that, the calculation is reached but always produces `0` so there is also something wrong with your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using MVVM pattern, so your callbacks should be in the 'code behind'.Use the WPF  auto-complete on:

MortgageCalculator.MainWindow

```
<Button Click="HERE!!!">
    <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="#FF7E7979" ShadowDepth="2"/>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

It will create the callback in the code behind (and not in the window as you did).
In MortgageCalculator.MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MortgageCalculator.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MortgageCalculator : UserControl
{
    public MortgageCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void somecallback(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the `return` statements that have been commented out or moved. Also, a corrected version of the payment calculation:

```
private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    {
        double monthlypayment = 0;

        //Tryparse for principal amount with error Red texbox
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtprincipal.Text) || !double.TryParse(txtprincipal.Text, out principal))
        {
            txtprincipal.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            return;
        }
        else
            txtprincipal.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);



        //Validate radio button
        if (rad10years.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            years = 10;
            //return;
        }
        else if (rad20years.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            years = 20;
            //return;
        }
        else if (rad30years.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            years = 30;
            //return;
        }
        else if (radother.IsChecked == true)
        {
            if (!double.TryParse(txtother.Text, out years))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a Valid year.");
                return;
            }
            //return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select number of years.");
            stkrdobtns.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            return;
        }

        //monthlypayment = ((principal * rate) / 1200) / Math.Pow(1 - (1.0 + rate / 1200), (-12.0 * years));

        var r = rate / 1200.0;
        var n = years * 12.0;
        monthlypayment = principal * ((r * Math.Pow((1 + r), n)) / (Math.Pow(1 + r, n) - 1));
        string MonthPay = string.Format("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0:c}", monthlypayment);
        MessageBox.Show(MonthPay);
    }
}
```